# Desktop folders are auto arranged after I add/delete some folder on desktop [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, .desktop, desktop-icons

Since I have upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 I am having this problem that Desktop folders are auto arranged whenever I add or delete some folder on desktop. Most of the times some certain folders leave their place but not all.